# PHP-CPP Versão da Compilação

Tags: php-cpp, extension

Estou com problema com uma extensão que estou compilando em PHP-CPP, pois quando compilo no meu Mac, a versão local dele é a 20121212, mas o meu Xampp é a versão 20131226, o problema é que em cada versão do php que ter uma compilação própria, senão não funciona. Como posso fazer uma compilação "universal"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infelizmente não tem como criar uma compilação universal, cada versão do php realmente possui diferentes compilações, isso ocorre em qualquer software, não só php.

Este problema ocorre por causa tipos diferentes de arquiteturas, como por exemplo:

- Diferentes processadores
- Diferentes sistemas operacionais
- Diferentes compiladores (mingw, msvc)
- Diferentes versões dos compiladores
- Diferentes versões de um mesmo sistemas operacionais

A build de uma versão especifica do *php* compilada é baseado na "arquitetura que foi compilada". Veja um exemplo, os Androids usam Java como linguagem e "gerenciador", isto porque um programa compilado em java não roda no dispositivo diretamente, ele roda na *"máquina virtual do java"* e por isso mesmo com tantos celulares e tablets com arquiteturas diferentes podem rodar um programa em diferentes processadores como ARM e Intel, pois cada Android para cada arquitetura de celular (com diferentes processadores) tem a sua própria versão do Java que é compatível com o processador usado no dispositivo.

Voltando a falar sobre compilação, a unica maneira de se ter algo universal no PHP é não usar extensões criadas por você e passar a usar os `.php` que não são compilados, mas sim "interpretados" e vão rodar em qualquer compilação do PHP, mesmo que de diferentes processadores.

> Note que muitas funcionalidades do php5.3 não funcionam no 5.2, como namespaces, assim como o php5.4 possui características que não são suportadas pelo 5.3, estamos aqui falando de arquitetura e não de versões do php.

Note que além de executar em servidores você pode executar o php por terminal e se for um ambiente like-unix ou uma "porta cgi" você pode criar um arquivo com uma extensão qualquer e aplicar o path do executável do php no inicio do código (eu não tenho certeza, me corrija se tiver confundido como preparar o script):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php-cgi
<?php
```

Ou então configurar a variável de ambiente `PATH` com o caminho do executável do PHP.

Se isto não é uma opção, então realmente você terá que compilar a extensão para cada versão do PHP, note isto http://windows.php.net/download:

- php7:

  - VC14 x86 Non Thread Safe
  - VC14 x86 Thread Safe
  - VC14 x64 Non Thread Safe
  - VC14 x64 Thread Safe
- php5.6:

  - VC11 x86 Non Thread Safe
  - VC11 x86 Thread Safe
  - VC11 x64 Non Thread Safe
  - VC11 x64 Thread Safe

Note que temos os termos VC11, x86, x64, NonThreadSafe e Thread Safe:

- VC11 indica que foi compilado na versão 11 do *VisualC++*
- VC14 indica que foi compilado na versão 14 do *VisualC++*
- x86 indica que foi compilado em um processado "32bit" assim como x64 indica que foi compilado em um processado "64bit"
- ThreadSafe (TS) trabalha com servidores multi-thread (Apache2 no Windows por exemplo) e Non ThreadSafe (NTS) indica se foi compilado.

  Thread Safety funciona criando uma cópia local em cada thread, de modo que os dados não colidirão com outra thread.

  O NTS não tem isto e ele é voltado para FastCGI por exemplo.

Então você terá que fazer extensões muito mais do que só compatível com o tipo de versão do PHP. Esse build (20131226) é mesmo voltado para evitar problemas.

O ambiente de compilação para qualquer tipo de software pode ser um pouco complicado mesmo, o que você pode fazer para facilitar é distribuir o source (muitos desenvolvedores fazem isto) e compilar ele direto na máquina que vai ser instalado, criando um arquivo `.bat` (no windows é provável que precise instalar um compilador) ou um bash no Linux (esse é o lado bom do linux, geralmente ele já vem com compilador).

Um exemplo é o proprio PHP, ele é distribuido em source também http://php.net/downloads.php (os arquivo .gz), as versões binarias na verdade acho que só existem pra windows, quem mantem as versões binarias em sistemas linux são os repositórios (acho que existe distros que compilam só depois de baixar pra máquina o php, ou seja trabalham com o source).

### Resumindo, as soluções são:

- Usar arquivos .php ao invés de extensões
- Compilar os sources diretamente nos servidores (se você pode instalar .so ou .dll em um servidor é bem provável que possa compilar algo nele também).